# Python wx-widgets in Alpine Linux

Tags: linux, python, alpine-linux

I'm trying to install Trelby in Alpine Linux.
When I launch python setup.py install, I get the following error:

```
alpine# python setup.py install                               
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 114, in <module>
import misc
File "src/misc.py", line 3, in <module>
import gutil
File "src/gutil.py", line 3, in <module>
import util
File "src/util.py", line 20, in <module>
import wx
ImportError: No module named wx
```

Now the trelby readme indicates these dependencies:

TRELBY REQUIREMENTS
External dependencies required:

1. Python 2.7
2. wxWidgets (2.8) and its Python bindings (wxPython)
3. lxml

I installed Trelby in Arch and Debian which indicate these dependencies:

ARCH

1. python2 (pypy19, stackless-python2, placeholder)
2. python2-lxml
3. python2-setuptools
4. wxpython (wxpython-nuitka, wxpython-gtk2, python2-wxpython3)

DEBIAN

1. python2
2. python-lxml
3. python-crypto
4. python-wxgtk3.0

In Alpine I installed the following packages:

ALPINE (installed)

1. python2, python2-dev
2. py-lxml, py2lxml, py3xlml
3. py-setuptools
4. wxgtk-base-3.0.3, wxgtk-3.0.3, wxgtk-dev, wxgtk2.8-dev, wxgtk2.8, wxgtk2.8-base

I also installed mock, py2-mock, py3-mock

And still I get the above error.

My question is: which package is missing, since I can't find any other wx widgets package that might fit the bill.
By the way, why do they not use all the same name for a certain package?

Comment: Probably `python-wxgtk3.0-dev` https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=python-wxgtk

Comment: that'd be in Debian, which I have no problems with. The problem is Alpine which seems not to have wxpython in the repo.